# Cutover migration Error: ProvisioningFailedException: The name "XXX" is already being used. Please try another name.

Tags: exchange, migration

I am performing a cutover migration from Exchange 2003 to Office 365

Before doing the migration I created a few users in the admin account.
I then set up the migration and executed it.

Each user which already existed, caused the error

```
ProvisioningFailedException: The name "XXX" is already being used. Please try another name.
```

So I deleted all the users except for me, and then attempted to perform the migration.
It now worked for all these users.

The only problem is that I could not delete my own user (the Admin user) and I also have a mailbox that I am trying to sync. So I am still getting the error.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can sync my own user? 
(I have a workaround - to export my stuff as a .pst and then import later -  but I would like an elegant way...)

, and then tried to perform the migration. The problem was that for each user which I had cre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround seems to be as follows:

1. Change my username - the one used to perform the migration - (in Admin/Users) to something else
2. Perform the migration
3. Assign the imported user as an administrator
4. Delete the user used to perform the migration